# How to set a property of a model as Fragment label in Navigation component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I am passing a `Category` model in a Fragment's arguments.  The model has two properties: `id` and `name`.

when I am trying to set `name` as the label of the Fragment, i.e.:

```
android:label="{category.name}"
```

it's giving me the following runtime exception:

> Could not find category.name in Bundle[{category=Category(id=7, name=Cloth drying stand)}] to fill label {category.name}

Answer (score -2):

You can also pass data in navigation component with safeargs as below for reference.
In app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

In top level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
classpath  'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
}
```

In navigation graph

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/employeeDetailsFragment"
    android:name="com.example.navigationjetpacksample.fragments.EmployeeDetailsFragment"
    android:label="EmployeeDetailsFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/frag_employee_details">
    <argument
        android:name="employee"
        app:argType="com.example.navigationjetpacksample.models.Employee"
        android:defaultValue="@null"
        app:nullable="true"/>
</fragment>
```

send arguments from one fragment to another

```
val action = EmployeesListFragmentDirections.actionEmployeesListFragmentToEmployeeDetailsFragment(getEmployee)
            view.findNavController().navigate(action)
```

and in your receiver fragment

```
val args : EmployeeDetailsFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding : FragEmployeeDetailsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
            R.layout.frag_employee_details,container,false)
        binding.employee = args.employee
        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: i am already using safeArgs but the question is how to set a property value in label using safeArgs

Comment: android:label="@{category.name}"

Comment: <data>
    <variable
        name="category"
        type="yourpackage.Category" />
    </data>